# jquery autocomplete suggestor Keyboard interaction(up and down)

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete, keyboard

I am trying to build suggestor after selecting jQuery Autocomplete suggested skills, after getting suggested skills I am not able to focus <kbd>↑</kbd> and <kbd>↓</kbd> using keyboard

**scenario 1:** Got suggestion from jQuery Autocomplete I can use keyboard <kbd>↑</kbd> and <kbd>↓</kbd>, can select a particular skills

**scenario 2:** After clicking on skill I populate another list which is stored in an array, it looks similar in terms of UI as jQuery Autocomplete show, how can I focus up and down using keyboard keys

```
$('.cls_auto_select_multi_val').keydown(function(e) {
  if(e.which == 40){
    $('#id_suggestor').find("li:first").next().focus()
    return ;
  }
});
```

1. I have two array in which second array contains `key` and `value`, problem which I am facing is how to focus first element of the list which is suggested from auto suggester, after writing 2 character focus should be back to input box.

Structure of Array :

```
[0:"Accounts",
1:"Engineering",
2:"Software",
3:"IT",
4:"HR",
5:"Sales",
6:"Finance"]
```

Comment: Please edit your post and include a more complete example.

Comment: Will need a more full example, including HTML. You may want to create a jsfiddle.net example. It's not clear what you need or what you're trying to accomplish.